# SQL Server : how to split single column into multi rows without create new function?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to find a way to split column to rows, but I can find many solutions of them are using function.

I am just curious can we do this without function?

Here is my sample data:

```
      id
value a, b, c, d, e
```

This is 1 COLUMN named id with value 'a, b, c, d, e'

I want to make them like

```
row 1 a
row 2 b
row 3 c
row 4 d
row 5 e
```

Comment: have you looked at using PIVOT?

Comment: post an example of the column data and how you want to split it

Comment: Can you provide a sample to describe your question more clearly?

Comment: You want to make entire column to a single row? Is there anything to group by?

Comment: I want to make them in multiple row

Comment: is that your a, b, c, d, e are 5 different columns, or just one column with data in comma separated format?

Comment: One column and delimited by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT`

Example:

```
DECLARE @PIVOTED TABLE
(   KEYVAL VARCHAR(50)
,   A INT
,   B INT
,   C INT
,   D INT
,   E INT)

INSERT INTO @PIVOTED 
( KEYVAL, A, B, C, D, E )
VALUES  
('Test 1', 1, 7, 6, 4, 3),('Test 2', 9, 3, 5, 4, 6)

SELECT
    KEYVAL
,   ABCKeys
,   ABCVals
FROM 
(   SELECT *
    FROM @PIVOTED
) p UNPIVOT
( ABCVals FOR ABCKeys IN ( A, B, C, D, E ) 
) AS unpvt
ORDER BY KEYVAL;
```